# Why can't my Office.js add-in find this Microsoft js resource (or why is it looking for it?)?

Tags: office-js

I get the following error in my console - it doesn't seem to effect functionality...but I don't like loose threads:

> Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404
>   (Not Found)
>   https://appsforoffice.microsoft.com/lib/1/hosted//ariatelemetry/aria-webjs-sdk-1.1.1.min.js.map

I only call:

```
<script src="https://appsforoffice.microsoft.com/lib/1/hosted/office.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Where is this 'ariatelemtry' coming in?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm guessing you are seeing this in the browser console. This is probably some internal tool used by office-js. It should be removed with the next possible update cycle to avoid seeing this error. In the meantime, this shouldn't impact the add-in in any way.